# Flutter: Cannot open file, path.= {assets/} , No such file or directory exists, [Errno 2]

Tags: flutter, dart, loading, assets

```
import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;   

List<Book> _items = [
        Book(
          id: 'b0',
          title: 'Subtle Art',
          authors: ['Mark Manson'],
          coverImage:
              img.decodeJpg(new File('assets/Subtle Art.jpg').readAsBytesSync()),
        )
      ];
```

**error no 2 is showing: No such file or directory exists**
**But there is assets folder with the image file in root folder and**
**in pubspec.yaml both**

```
assets:
- 'assets/Subtle Art.jpg'
```

Comment: did you try using removing space from image name ? like `Subtle_Art.jpg`

Comment: assume that you've put the path in pubspec.yaml corectly, try flutter clean, restart vscode or whatever editor you're using and run flutter pub get

Answer (score 0):

In flutter you unfortunately can't directly access the "assets" directory.
If you want to consume assets this is the proper way to do it: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images

I recommend you to also use https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider to access to anywhere else on your phone.